# Preventing hotlinking of certain filetypes in certain directories

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I'd like to prevent hotlinking of pdfs in a certain website directory without imposing a site-wide ban, and redirect any direct traffic to a given page. I suspect htaccess is my friend for this but don't know how I should define these rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/ /given-page.html [L,R]
```

Here, any request for anything in the folder `/folder/` that is not referred to by your site (example.com) will be redirected to `/given-page.html`.

Comment: Although this solution doesn't restrict the rule to one filetype (not sure if that's possible anyway) so long as the files are in their own directory as they are for me it works fine.

Comment: @AidanAshby you can restrict by file extension by adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.pdf$ [NC]` before the `RewriteRule` line (example is pdf, but you can change it to whatever).